# Can I modify the content of the left hand sidebar for contacts tab?

Tags: community

I want to modify the content of the left hand sidebar for contacts tab or any tab for that matter. I'd like to avoid recreating the object w visual force.

Thanks,
Zachary

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change the content of sidebar component but if you change the sidebar component content  it will reflect on all the tabs because this sidebar component is used by every tab so the change on sidebar component change will show on every tab where this  sidebar is enable

you can provide the content of side bar in home page layout and then assign the home pagelayout to your profile. This layout contain the content of side bar and show all the user to who have same profile and in all object tabs.

this is the link how to customize the sidebar component 
http://na11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_home_page_components.htm