# Tab-independent "global" VF page and controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, tab

We have a community set up with the standard Tabs + VF template. It's working pretty well, but we are trying to fulfill a requirement that we aren't sure how to do. We need a pretty simple drop-down that must be available on any tab, and selecting a different value in the drop-down should do some simple work and refresh the page you are on to reflect the changes. Ideally we'd like to style it so it's above the tabs and somewhere in the header space, for example next to the search bar.

Is it possible to do this with some sort of a "global" page and controller? We want it to work with out-of-the-box tabs, and business should be able to add new tabs to the community without having to bug the devs to add custom code to each new tab for the drop-down to work.

We have the drop-down fully working on a specific tab, we just want it to be visible regardless of which tab you are on.

I'm thinking maybe the sidebar might work? We don't use it right now, and it seems it's possible to make the sidebar show up on any page, while the code is modified only on the "home" page.
[Can I modify the content of the left hand sidebar for contacts tab?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15309/can-i-modify-the-content-of-the-left-hand-sidebar-for-contacts-tab)